# Fetching video information using oEmbed without API key - Is it deprecated? Any limitations?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, oembed

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve video information by using the video ID. My current approach involves making an API request to my backend with the video ID, and the server returns information such as author, thumbnail URL, duration, etc.

I came across the oEmbed feature, specifically using the URL https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID. This method works great for my needs, but I have some concerns after reading about the YouTube Data API, particularly the [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint. With this endpoint, I can also fetch video information using the video ID, but it requires an API key and has limitations on the number of requests per day due to [Google's quotas](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).

My questions are:

1. Is oEmbed deprecated or safe to use in production?
2. Are there any limitations to using oEmbed for fetching video
   information as my backend could make many requests when I don't make the oEmbed from the client side?
3. Why should I enable the [oEmbed API in my Google Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/youtubeoembed.googleapis.com) without needing an API key? Is this a recommended approach?

I have not been able to find any clear documentation about the current state of oEmbed and its limitations, so any insights or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is 10000 reqs/day too few for your needs?